# JMX on Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmx

I have annotated a class as follows:

```
@ManagedResource(objectName="com.myproject.bean.jmx:name=JMXSolrIndexerBean",
        description="Index Solr Operations")
public class JMXSolrIndexerBean {

....
}
```

My pom has the following dependencies

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can't find my MBean in the JConsole... are there any configuration steps I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. You don't need the `spring-integrtation-jmx` dependency to make that work, the actuator starter is enough
2. Your class needs to be a spring bean if you want Spring Boot to auto-detect JMX annotation on them. So adding `@Component` on your `JMXSolrIndexerBean` is all that's needed as long as it is located in a package that is processed by component scan

In other words, that class of yours is just a pojo that spring know nothings about. `@ManagedResource` is not a stereotype that turns that class in a Spring Bean.